# Do assembly programmers capitalize all the mnemonics when they are typing out their code?

Tags: assembly

Looking at almost any assembly language, all the mnemonics are documented as short, entirely capitalized keywords, like "MOV".

Do people working on assembly take the effort to keep all their mnemonics capitalized, or do they leave them lowercase?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [When did assembly source code begin to be written in lowercase?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23802)  I only use upper-case like OR when mixing when mentioning mnemonics or register names in sentences of English text, when I don't want it to be as eye-catching as `mov` code formatting.  Oh, turns out I recently wrote [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095069/mips-32-opcode-format-uppercase-or-lowercase) saying the same thing.

Comment: Some do, some don't.

Comment: The original MS-DOS Debug always wrote its disassembly mnemonics, size and pointer keywords, and register and numeric operands in allcaps. The clone FreeDOS Debug did the same. In [my fork](https://pushbx.org/ecm/web/#projects-ldebug) however I added an option (default on) to not capitalise things other than numeric digits (A to F in hexadecimal numbers).